# Optimisation problem. Maximising revenue of pies sold

Tags: calculus

Currently, you sell 600 pies a day at 20 dollars per pie. For each 10 cents increase (respectively decrease) in the price of pie, the number of pies you sell will decrease(respectively increase by 20).What price will you sell to maximise your total revenue?
I am not sure how to do this problem. How do i write the revenue function?

Comment: For 10 cents increase in price of pie, the number sold decreases by 20?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Conversely when price of pie decrease by 10 cents, number sold will increase by 20

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question.  You can delete it if you no longer wish to have it on the site, but changing it significantly invalidates the answers you have already received and is rather disrespectful of the time the answerers have taken to try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of demand function $Q=aP+b$:
$$\begin{cases}600=20a+b\\ 580=20.1a+b\end{cases} \Rightarrow a=-200,b=4600 \Rightarrow\\
Q=-200P+4600 \Rightarrow P=23-\frac{Q}{200}$$
The revenue function:
$$R=PQ=(23-\frac{Q}{200})Q=-\frac{Q^2}{200}+23Q\\
R'=-\frac{Q}{100}+23=0 \Rightarrow Q=2300 \Rightarrow P=23-\frac{Q}{200}=11.5.$$

Answer (score 0):

$n(p) = 600-200(p-20) = 200(23-p)$.

$r(p) = p\cdot n(p) = 200 p (23-p)$.

Solve $r'(p) = 0$ for $p$ and check that $p \ge 0$.

Comment: Hi i am not sure how did you get n(p). Can you explain how you got -200(p-20)? Thanks!

Comment: I read your description and wrote down the formula. You know it has the form $ap+b$ for some constants $a,b$. you know that $20a+b = 600$. You know that $20.1a+b = 580$. Figure out $a,b$.